# why is u8 u16 u32 u64 used instead of unsigned int in kernel programming

Tags: c, linux, kernel, linux-device-driver

I see u8 u16 u32 u64 data types being used in kernel code. And I am wondering why is there need to use `u8` or `u16` or `u32` or `u64` and not `unsigned int`?

Comment: Because that will only map to *one* of your list. And you can't be sure which one.

Comment: I've mostly seen the standard typedefs `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, et al.

Comment: I have linux/types.h include

Comment: what is the shorthand of signed 32?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Often when working close to the hardware or when trying to control the size/format of a data structure you need to have precise control of the size of your integers.

As for `u8` vs `uint8_t`, this is simply because Linux predated `<stdint.h>` being available in C, which is technically a C99-ism, but in my experience is available on most modern compilers even in their ANSI-C / C89 modes.

Comment: And `u8` involves less typing :-)

Comment: True... but it gets super annoying when you need to mix & match libraries and everyone tries to define their own known-wdith types so.   You'll have `U8`, `u8`, `uint8`, `BYTE`, `UINT8` and `unt8_t` all in the same file.  You can even have potential conflicts that ends up generating warnings.  Most commonly with the 32 and 64-bit types which may have multiple valid ways to typedef them on a given platform.   For new code, please, please, please just stick with stdint.h types :).

Comment: I am using `u8` `u16` etc in kernel space with `linux/types.h`. Is `stdint.h` for user space?

Comment: You can use the standard names (`uint8_t`, etc) in kernel mode too. Typedefs for those are in `linux/types.h` as well.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland as long as `u8` etc are your *own* typedefs that you can guarantee are identical to the standard ones, you'll be fine though. As Gil Hamilton said, [the kernel does this](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/types.h)

Answer (score 9):

Adding my 10 cents to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30896945/1582649):

`u64` means an 'unsigned 64 bits' value, so, depending on the architecture where the code will run/be compiled, it must be defined differently in order to really be 64 bits long.

For instance, on a x86 machine, an `unsigned long` is 64 bits long, so `u64` for that machine could be defined as follows:

`typedef unsigned long u64;`

The same applies for `u32`. On a x86 machine, `unsigned int` is 32 bits long, so `u32` for that machine could be defined as follows:

`typedef unsigned int u32;`

You'll generally find the `typedef` declaration for these types on a `types.h` file which corresponds to the architecture you're compiling your source to.

Answer (score 9):

Share what I learned about this question recently.

The reason why we need such **explicitly sized type**, such as u32, is that the normal C data types are not the same size on all architectures.

The following image shows that long integers and pointers feature a different size on various platforms.

[image]

In this way, u32 can guarantee that you get 4 bytes long integer.